# How to split the joined contours in opencv python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

How to split the two characters in the image which are joined.

Refer the below image,

[image]

I want to split as MENT

[image]

and for the second image as IN.

```
import cv2;
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im_in = cv2.imread("testResize.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); 
th, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_in, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
h, w = im_th.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(im_th, kernel, iterations=2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is my original image,
 [image]

I wanted to read the image as "INSTRUMENT CLUSTER"

Since the letters are joined, I get the wrong text.so I wanted to split the joined letters

Comment: I think your problem is that the solution you are after is fairly arbitary. What's the difference between splitting IN and something else?

Comment: Indeed, the only way to know where to split is to recognize the letters.

Comment: Can you upload the original image? If not try blurring the image before applying a threshold and then proceed as usual

Comment: Kindly see my updated post

Comment: Erosion. Also, post the whole image.

Comment: The third image is the original image